# How many quarter horses?

Tags: arithmetic

The rent-a-stall horse barn has stalls for 1000

horses. Forty percent of the stalls are for ponies.

On Tuesday, there were 200 ponies and a bunch of

quarter horses at the horse barn. The horse barn

was 75 percent full.

How many quarter horses were in the stalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 40% number is irrelevant

$200 + h = .75 \times 1000$

$h=550$

Comment: You could also show that there **are** $550$ quarter-horse stalls...